# OpenNLP creating Annotator

Tags: java, annotations, nlp, opennlp

I used to use Stanford CoreNLP, and I would like to investigate OpenNLP this time.
Is it possible to create your own Annotator?
For example, I would like to analyze a text and pick out only colors, or aircraft names.

Stanford NER lets me to create my own NER model to do so.

Any suggestion??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I find training in opennlp much easier than in corenlp. Pretty straightforward and documented a.o here: [Training own model in opennlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204352/training-own-model-in-opennlp)

Comment: and here's the latest OpenNLP 1.8.1 documentation to help you - please reach us out on users@opennlp.apache.org with any questions. http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/manual/opennlp.html

Comment: ah yes, sorry for not linking to the original docs directly. They are very helpful and well-maintained too.